# How to add two stored values by load in assembly using 1 addressing mode?

Tags: assembly, 6502

I want to add two values x and y which are stored but I only want to use 1 addressing mode.
Following is the example:

```
lda x
sta x
// store the final result in x


lda y
sta y
// store the final result in y

//now I want to add x and y like x+y. Is the following pattern correct? whats wrong? 
lda x
lda y
add x
sta x
```

Comment: That's not x86 please use correct architecture tag. Anyway, `lda y` after `lda x` will overwrite the loaded value. You just need to load `x` then add `y`. Easy.  That said, your code should work, but the `lda x` is unnecessary.

Comment: how can I add y. y is not loaded before adding it.

Comment: `lda x; add y; sta result`. Or, `lda y; add x; sta result`.

Comment: please add this answer to answer box so that I could accept it.

Answer (score 7):

> Is the following pattern correct? whats wrong?

No.

- Addition is always done with the accumulator.
- There is no `ADD` instruction only `ADC` add with carry
- You need to manage the carry flag.

If you have two memory locations x and y and you want to store the result in x, the cannonical way to do this is:

```
; x = x + y
LDA x      ; Load one operand into the accumulator.
CLC        ; Clear the carry flag so it does not get added into the result
ADC y      ; Add the other operand
STA x      ; Store the operand back to x
```

You can use any address mode for y and any address mode for x except immediate.

If x and y are the addresses of 16 bit values, the 16 bit addition will look like this:

```
LDA x      ; Load one operand into the accumulator.
CLC        ; Clear the carry flag so it does not get added into the result
ADC y      ; Add the other operand
STA x      ; Store the operand back to x
LDA x+1    ; Now do the high byte
ADC y+1    ; Note we do not clear the carry this time.
STA x+1
```

Answer (score 5):

Additions on the 6502 are done exclusively in the accumulator.

- Load the first number in the accumulator
- Add the second number to the accumulator
- Store the accumulator in memory

### Z=X+Y

```
lda x
add y
sta z  ;Leaves x and y unchanged
```

### X=X+Y

```
lda x
add y
sta x
```

### X=Y+X

What your program did produces the same result as my second snippet. The  order in which you add is not important (not so for the subtraction!) Do notice that it is useless to load the accumulator with x only to reload it directly after with y!

```
lda x   ;This is useless
lda y
add x
sta x
```

As [others have commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47208154/how-to-add-two-stored-values-by-load-in-assembly-using-1-addressing-mode/47228470#comment81410546_47228470), there's no `add` instruction in the 6502 instruction set, nor is there a `sub` instruction. However I am willing to give you the benefit of the doubt since it's perfectly OK to have a few macros defined in order to avoid having to write `clc` and `sec` every time you start a fresh addition or subtraction.

Example of `add` using modern day FASM syntax:

```
macro add op
 {
  clc
  adc op
 }
```

Example of `sub` using very old METACOMCO syntax:

```
sub MACRO
    sec
    sbc \1
    ENDM
```

Comment: The 6502 lacks straight addition though, you'll want a `CLC + ADC` sequence. Then again given the original code and confused ISA attribution this may well be 6800 code.

Comment: There's no `ADD` instruction in 6502

Comment: @JeremyP Could you agree that, on the 6502, it makes sense to define `add` and `sub` macros to avoid having to write `clc` and `sec` ?

Comment: Yes you could create those macros and I don't see any reason not to, but I've never seen it done.

Answer (score 4):

If this should really be 6502 code, the opcode for addition is `adc` which means "*add with carry*". There's no addition operation *without* carry available.

`lda` loads the *accumulator* with a value, so two `lda` in direct sequence are utterly useless. Just use one `lda` followed by an `adc` (which will add whatever you address to the accumulator *and* add the carry flag).

All in all, the sequence looks simply like:

```
lda x
adc y
sta x
```

where `x` and `y` could for example be absolute addresses.

**But**  be *aware* of the carry flag! If you have no way to know the status of carry, you need a `clc` (*clear carry*) instruction first. If you *know* that carry will be set, and `y` is an immediate value, just add one less. If you can't do that, you need a `clc` as well.

In general, always try to avoid the `clc` (it takes a byte and some cycles, which indeed matters on such a limited chip), but sometimes you *will* need it.

---

Real-world example of code that can avoid the `clc` (part of a [double dabble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dabble) implementation):

```
nts_addloop:    lda     nc_string,x
                cmp     #$5           ; value >= 5 ?
                bcc     nts_noadd     ; after not branching here, we know C=1
                adc     #$2           ; then add 3 (2 + carry)
                sta     nc_string,x
nts_noadd:      dex
```

Real-world example of code that *needs* `clc` (part of a [long multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm#Long_multiplication) implementation):

```
mul_rorloop:    ror     mpm_arg1,x
                dex
                bpl     mul_rorloop
                bcc     mul_noadd      ; we know carry is set when not branching
                ldx     #($80-NUMSIZE)
                clc                    ; clear it because we have to add a variable value
mul_addloop:    lda     mpm_arg2+NUMSIZE-$80,x
                adc     mpm_res+NUMSIZE-$80,x
                sta     mpm_res+NUMSIZE-$80,x
                inx
                bpl     mul_addloop
mul_noadd:      ldx     #($81-NUMSIZE)
```

Comment: You can't avoid using `clc` when doing a new addition (as opposed to the high order bytes of a multibyte number), unless you already know the state of the carry flag.

Comment: @JeremyP which is what I wrote?

Comment: You wrote "In general, always try to avoid the `clc`" whereas, in fact, it should be more or less automatic to put it in.

Comment: @JeremyP you should read the whole answer, I first explained when/how you can avoid it. On a 6502, a redundant `clc` is bad practice.

Comment: In most cases you do not know the state of the carry flag. Even if you have just tested it with `BCS` or `BCC` you do not know if some other code jumps direct to the bit of code that does the add. It's bad practice to leave out the `CLC` unless you know. It's one byte and two clock cycles, that's all.

Comment: @JeremyP That's wrong. You know the state of the flags more often than not. Pieces of code jumping directly to a location where you add something are just a sign you totally lost track of your code. Every byte and every cycle is precious on a 6502.

Comment: Seriously? You know the state of the C flag when you come in to an add sequence? I'm afraid that is rubbish and it is also very bad programming practice to make assumptions like that. A sequence of instructions that do a addition are is more robust and reusable if you don't assume the state of the C flag before you start.

Comment: @JeremyP It doesn't look like you have much experience programming a 6502. Yes, I'm analyzing my code and in the majority of cases, I can tell the state of the C flag.

Comment: If you are going to insult me fine. You are advocating bad practice and that is what I would expect from an amateur. This conversation is over.

Comment: @JeremyP You're the one advocating bad practice. It's amateurs' code where you see redundant instructions (like an unnecessary `clc`), often even inside loops. You're clearly confusing "good practice" nowadays in modern languages on modern hardware in presence of optimizing compilers with good practice on a very limited old hardware programmed in machine code.